# Why does this simple C example end in a segfault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The following simple example results in a segmentation fault when attempting to access the first element of `m` inside `main`.

Why does this happen?

How can I fix it, but still keep the overall structure of the code the same?

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double *array(int cols) {
  return malloc(cols*sizeof(double));
}

void create_and_modify_array(double *m) {
  m = array(10);
  m[0] = 123;
}

void main() {
  double *m;
  create_and_modify_array(m);
  printf("%f\n", m[0]);
}
```

Comment: You never change the `m` in `main`. The `m` in `mess_around_with_matrix` is a *copy* of the `m` in main.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that C is always pass by value. Pass by value means that function arguments are *copies* of the variables they were called with. This means when you do this:

```
m = array(10);
```

inside `create_and_modify_array(double *m)`, you are only changing where the function's local copy of `m` points. The `m` pointer from the main method is unaffected (and stays uninitialised, hence the crash).

To fix this, you can pass a pointer to the `main()`'s `m` pointer:

```
void create_and_modify_array(double **m) {
  *m = array(10); // change the pointer that `m` points to
  (*m)[0] = 123;  // assign something to the first element of what `m` points to
}
```

And pass the address of `main()`'s `m` in:

```
void main() {
  double *m; // make a pointer to a double
  create_and_modify_array(&m); // pass a pointer to the pointer to the double
                               // or, in alternative wording: 
                               // pass the address of the pointer to the double
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the pointer created in `create_and_modify_array` is a different address than the one declared and used in `main()`. You can do this instead

```
double *create_and_modify_array(double *m) {
  m = array(10);
  m[0] = 123;
  return m;
}

void main() {
  double *m = create_and_modify_array(m);
  printf("%f\n", m[0]);
  free (m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It segfaults because m inside `create_and_modify_array` is a local variable, so m inside `main` is still uninitialised.

To be more explicit the code flow is:

at the start of `main` `m` is a random, unassigned memory address. Then it calls `create_and_modify_array` with that memory address. Inside `create_and_modify_array` a new variable called `m` is created, and it has that random, unassigned memory address that was passed in. Then you call `array` and the variable `m` inside `create_and_modify_array` is assigned to your allocated memory.

The problem is that that value of `m` never gets passed back to the `m` in `main`.

To do that you need to pass a pointer to main's `m` into `create_and_modify_array`:

```
void create_and_modify_array (double **m) {
    double *tmp = array(10);
    tmp[0] = 123;
    *m = tmp; // This passes the value of tmp back to the main function.
              // As m in this function is actually the address of m in main
              // this line means put tmp into the thing that is at this address
}

void main () {
    double *m;
    create_and_modify_array (&m); // This passes the address of the variable m
                                  // into create_and_modify_array
    printf ("%f\n", m[0]);
}
```